# Bank account in Germany for non-EU-residents?

Tags: bank-account, germany

I am a Brazilian student with a German PhD contract scheduled to start on April 1st, but due to the COVID pandemic which is significantly bad in Brazil, the local German consulate cancelled all visa appointments for an unknown time. In order to not delay the contract, I need to (among other requirements) open an account in a German bank.

However, most banks I found require a residence permit, which I of course do not have yet. Is there a bank for non-EU-residents that I could use? Since I have the contract ready, I'm okay with some small monthly fee.

I looked at the answers for [this question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/24456/bank-account-in-germany-for-non-residents) but they all seem to only apply for EU residents :(

Answer (score 2):

You very likely need a SEPA bank account (with IBAN).

I suggest you try either a brazilian Bank with an office in Germany, as for example [Banco do Brasil](https://www.bb.com.br/pbb/pagina-inicial/atendimento/bb-no-mundo/banco-do-brasil-in-deutschland#/), or get in contact with the brazilian (or portuguese as a fallback) diaspora living in Germany. Usually one can find such groups on facebook or other social networks, and depending on where you are located, some local cultural associations.

You are probably not the first one going through something similar, you may be able to get specialized help there.

You may also explain the situation to your future employer, and they may be willing to transfer the money internationally for a few months, until you get your paperwork straight, but it is probably a bureaucratic nightmare, so it should probably be avoided.